# Unicode-math: substitute \perp for \bot

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

Using *unicode-math* with LuaTeX.  The font *Fira Math* is missing some glyphs that I use, notably the symbol for `\bot`.  I know that I can grab it from a different font:

```
\setmathfont[range={"022A5}]{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}
```

but that bloats my PDF with yet another font.  Alternatively, I can redefine the command `\bot`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bot}{\mathord{\perp}}}
```

but that's exactly the wrong level — a glyph substitution shouldn't require modifying TeX's input syntax.  The obvious solution would be to perform the subsitution at the *luaotfload* level,

```
  \directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
      name = "bottoperp",
      type = "substitute",
      data = {
        [0x22A5] = {0x27C2},
      },
    }
  }
  \setmathfont{Fira Math}[RawFeature=+bottoperp]
```

but that appears to do nothing.

What is the right way to substitute a glyph with *LuaTeX* and *unicode-math*?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If \perp is the symbol you want, then why don't you use it?

Comment: \bot is the symbol I want, and it's not in the font.

Comment: \perp works fine for me,

Comment: I has the wrong spacing, compare `$x = \bot$` with `$x = \perp$`.  Redefining `\bot` to `{\perp}` works fine, due to the extra set of brackets, not sure if it will cause any other trouble.

Comment: Well U+22A4 (\bot, UP TACK) is defined as a \mathord in unicode-math, U+27C2 (\perp, PERPENDICULAR) is a \mathrel, so yes their spacing is different, but they have also a different unicode code point and meaning, so if you want U+22A5, then you should get it either from another font, or map it with addfeature, so that the to unicode value is right.

Comment: Strangely enough, addfeature (type=substitution) works if I apply it to *XITS Math*, but doesn't appear to do anything with *Fira Math*.  Perhaps a subsitution only works if the glyph being substituted is already in the font?

Comment: Why not `{\perp}`, or `\mathord{\perp}`, to change the spacing? Aliased to a semantic name?

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but it's a hackish workaround, not a solution.  It perpetuates the confusion between (1) markup, (2) characters, and (3) glyphs.  I have an issue at level (3), and I'm fixing it at level (1).  (That's the very reason why I'm using LuaTeX rather than XeTeX, although the latter is four times faster — the former allows me to fix font issues at level (3), which causes way fewer issues than fixing them at the TeX macro level.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `newunicodechar` to make the character active, you can adjust the mathcode of `\bot` to use the glyph for `\perp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  % For U+22A5, use class \mathord (0), family 0 and glyph U+27C2
  \Umathcode"22A5 0 0 "27C2
}

\begin{document}

$a\bot b$ or $a ⊥ b$

$a\perp b$ or $a ⟂ b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make `⊥` active and define it to be `\bot`, but redefining this one to be `{\perp}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

% there is no \bot in Fira Sans
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bot}{{\perp}}}
\newunicodechar{⊥}{\bot}

\begin{document}

$a\bot b$ or $a ⊥ b$

$a\perp b$ or $a ⟂ b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The picture shows that `⊥` (U+22A5) is treated as an ordinary symbol and `⟂` (U+27C2) as a relation symbol.

Comment: That works around the actual issue, but just like redefining the `\bot` macro, it's the wrong level — I should be able to substitute a glyph without munging the input syntax.

Comment: @jch I'm not sure I understand. Anyway, I added to my example and your doubts should go away.

Comment: Greg, anything can be fixed with TeX macros, that's how we got into the mess we're in.  LuaTeX holds the promise of fixing things at the font level when they are font issues, rather than building dozens of font-specific hacks at the TeX macro level, which interact in marvellous ways with the other font-specific hacks.

Comment: Is `newunicodechar` good style in the context of LuaTeX/XeTeX and `unicode-math`? I had kinda convinced myself that it was only supposed to be used with pdfTeX.

Comment: @Gaussler It was born for `pdflatex`, but extending it to Unicode engines was easy. What it does is to make the character active and to give it a `\protected` definition.

Comment: So LuaTeX does not have the power to actually change the glyphs produced by characters without making those characters active? Imagine, say, that I would like to have all `e`’s rendered as `a`’s, but without breaking commands like `\def`?

Comment: @Gaussler I believe that you can tell LuaTeX to use for a character a glyph at a different code point.

Comment: Thank you, @agrag. `;-)`